# update to angular10, canvas image disorder

Tags: angular, typescript

I have updated angular from 9.0 to 10.1. The problem is that the canvas image is out of order. If I click Status Tab, image will be disorder.

Angular 9 is ok, but angular 10.1 is not ok.

**HTML**

```
<canvas [id]='canvasId'></canvas>
```

**TypeScript**

```
this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId) as any;
```

I suspect there are two canvass, the old canvas is still exists.
Can some one give me ideas?

[ok_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV6Cs.png)

[wrong_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq2kb.png)

Comment: The canvas obtained through getelementbyid is not the same as the canvas displayed in the interface

Comment: I need to clear the canvas for redrawing other images after routing.

Answer (score 0):

prop.solution:

```
let cdtGraphDiv = document.getElementById('cdtGraphDiv');
cdtGraphDiv.innerHTML = '';
cdtGraphDiv.append('<canvas id="cdtGraphview"><canvas>');


<div id="cdtGraphDiv">
   <canvas id="cdtGraphview"></canvas>
</div>
```

I remove and re-create canvas in div. This work fine.
**And I still don't know why there are two canvas.**